# How to add IMG with in ANCHOR while using link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a link(HTML Anchor Tag) that contains an img Tag element in my application. I used link_to to produce links but don't know how to generate HTML tags within them.

Do i need to use javascript/jQuery rather than trying it in my application. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here it should look like

```
<a href='/groceries'>
   <img src="location" alt="Groceries.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in documentation, anchor seems as:

```
<%= link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, anchor: "wall") %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

For your case:

```
<%= link_to groceies_path(anchor: 'header') do %>
  <%= image_tag('test.png', alt: 'Grocieries') %>
<% end %>
```